# Identity Server 4 and UWP on Localhost

Tags: uwp, localhost, identityserver4

I'm hoping for some help getting the Identity Server 4 Demo (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo) and the OidcClient Samples UWP Client (https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples) working on localhost.

I've downloaded both and they both run. I can access localhost:5000 from a web browser and it loads up identity server's home page. In the uwp sample when I click Login it returns an "Unknown error". If I point the uwp sample to demo.identityserver.io it works so the sample works just not on localhost.

The identity server logs show some activity, no errors, but a breakpoints on the login method never gets hit. I thought it might be local loopback but on windows 10 with visual studio 2017 local loopback is no longer an issue as far as I'm aware. Has anyone been able to get these two samples to work together?

Thanks

Comment: From what I can tell it needs to run over https with a valid cert to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP's internal WAB (web authentication browser) will only work if you pointing a an https side and the site has a valid certificate. Once I setup localhost to use https and gave it a cert it all started working!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it locally by disabling Loopback,
as I'm doing it right now!
See [here](http://kevinchalet.com/2016/08/22/using-a-local-oauth2-openid-connect-server-with-webauthenticationbroker/) for more information